# aus etwas werden v.s. werden

Tags: difference, meaning-in-context, phrase

I read a sentence

> Mein Gott - was soll aus Deutschland werden

from: 
http://www.spiegel.de/spiegel/print/d-43366453.html

I guess the meaning is "My God, what will Germany become?".
My question is: why do we have a "aus" here? Does it give any additional meaning here? Is the sentence different from "was soll Deutschland werden"?

What is the declarative sentence form(not question form)? "Aus Deutschland wird eine gute Land." ?

Here is another more complicated and special example(from "Versionkontrolle mit Git"):

> Bei der normalen Anwendung von git clone werden aus den lokalen
>   Entwicklungszweigen des Original-Repository, die in refs/heads/
>   gespeichert sind, die entfernten TrackingZweige im neuen Klon unter
>   refs/remotes/.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The meaning of your example is closer to

> What will become of Germany?

instead of

> What will Germany become?

Using "aus" puts emphasis on the fact that Germany will evolve/develop **into** something; its meaning is somewhat closer to **"What will Germany evolve into?"** than it is to "What will it become?"

Quote from the `duden.de` article about "aus":

> zur Angabe eines früheren Entwicklungsstadiums in Verbindung mit Verben, die ein Werden bezeichnen. Beispiele:
>   - aus den Raupen entwickeln sich Schmetterlinge
>   - aus seiner Tochter wurde eine tüchtige Ärztin

Comment: Using "aus" puts emphasis on the fact that Germany will evolve/develop **starting from the existing state** into another state.

Comment: What is the declarative sentence form(not question form)? "Aus Deutschland wird eine gute Land." ?

Comment: "Aus Deutschland wird ein gutes Land" - although that sounds kinda weird, much like "Germany will become a good country" in english would.
What is it you're trying to say?

Comment: @PixelMaster, I am confused about the subject of the sentence which in this case is in fact a phrase "Aus Deutschland". I would normally expect a noun, since it is rare to use "Zu Hause", "Auf der Strasse", .. etc as subjects of sentences.

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what you mean, but the sentence "Deutschland wird ein gutes Land" (without "aus") is also correct, albeit weird. Adding "aus" simply gives additional information here.  "Zu Hause" on the other hand belongs together and neither of the words can be omitted without rendering the sentence invalid.

Answer (score -2):

I guess the problem simply lies in the different meanings, especially since 1 and 2 also may be combined.

```
1) become (as in example 1 and 2). The starting state of the object becoming something is typically referred to by "aus".
2) indicator for future tense (Ich werde reisen, I will travel)
3) indicator for passive perfect (Ich werde geküsst, I get kissed)
```

Comment: There is no passive in "werden aus den lokalen x die entfernten x" or in any of the other examples